# Why do I get so many `LNK2005` errors despite using `#ifndef #define #endif` code blocks in my .h files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, linker, lnk2005

I have 21 files as shown here in the picture:

[image]

The following 35 functions are declared in lines 364-411 of `util.h` inside a

```
#ifndef FlagUtil

#define FlagUtil

#endif
```

code block:

```
Create_Pix, Remove_Pix, my_round, edit_error, check_file, check_dir, 
read_config, write_config, write_envi_config, my_randomize, my_random, 
my_eps_random, cadd, csub, cmul, cdiv, cpwr, cconj, cimg, crel, cmod, cmod2, 
angle, cplx_sinc, PolTypeConfig, init_file_name, memory_alloc, PrintfLine, 
CreateUsageHelpDataFormat, CreateUsageHelpDataFormatInput, 
init_matrix_block, block_alloc, CheckFreeMemory, CheckFreeMemoryWin32, 
CheckFreeMemoryLinux
```

The following 30 functions are declared in lines 99-135 of `util_block.h` inside a

```
#ifndef FlagUtilBlock

#define FlagUtilBlock

#endif
```

code block:

```
read_matrix_int, read_matrix_float, read_matrix_cmplx, write_matrix_int, 
write_matrix_float, write_matrix_cmplx, read_matrix3d_float, 
read_matrix3d_cmplx, write_matrix3d_float, write_matrix3d_cmplx, 
read_block_matrix_int, read_block_matrix_float, 
read_block_matrix_matrix3d_float, read_block_matrix_cmplx, 
write_block_matrix_int, write_block_matrix_float, 
write_block_matrix_matrix3d_float, write_block_matrix_cmplx, 
write_block_matrix3d_float, write_block_matrix3d_cmplx, read_block_S2_avg, 
read_block_S2_noavg, read_block_S2T6_avg, read_block_SPP_avg, 
read_block_SPP_noavg, read_block_TCI_avg, read_block_TCI_noavg, 
read_block_S2_TCIelt_noavg, read_block_SPP_TCIelt_noavg, average_TCI
```

The following 35 functions are declared in lines 106-149 of `util_convert.h` inside a

```
#ifndef FlagUtilConvert

#define FlagUtilConvert

#endif
```

code block:

```
S2_to_C3elt, S2_to_C4elt, S2_to_T3elt, S2_to_T4elt, S2_to_T6elt, 
SPP_to_C2elt, SPP_to_T2elt, S2_to_SPP, S2_to_IPP, S2_to_C2, S2_to_C3, 
S2_to_C4, S2_to_T2, S2_to_T3, S2_to_T4, S2_to_T6, SPP_to_C2, SPP_to_T2, 
SPP_to_IPP, SPP_to_T4, C2_to_IPP, C2_to_T2, T2_to_C2, C4_to_T4, C4_to_C3, 
C4_to_T3, C4_to_C2, C4_to_IPP, T4_to_C4, T4_to_C3, T4_to_T3, C3_to_T3, 
C3_to_C2, C3_to_IPP, T3_to_C3, T6_to_C3
```

And the contents of the file `PolSARproLib.h` is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <dos.h>
#include <conio.h>
#endif

/* ROUTINES DECLARATION */
#include "util.h"
#include "util_block.h"
#include "util_convert.h"
#include "graphics.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "processing.h"
#include "statistics.h"
#include "sub_aperture.h"
#include "my_utils.h"
```

And the contents of the file `PolSARproLib.c` is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <dos.h>
#include <conio.h>
#endif

/* ROUTINES DECLARATION */
#include "util.c"
#include "util_block.c"
#include "util_convert.c"
#include "graphics.c"
#include "matrix.c"
#include "processing.c"
#include "statistics.c"
#include "sub_aperture.c"
#include "my_utils.c"
```

I’ve placed those 21 files in a folder named `Static Project` and I’ve created the `PolSARproLib.lib` file as follows, my machine is a Win 10x64 one: ([here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx_9vCAvXd5kTzBwZ2hRSm1WV2s) I’ve uploaded this project):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The files `graphics.obj`, `matrix.obj`, `my_utils.obj`, `PolSARproLib.lib`, `PolSARproLib.obj`, `processing.obj`, `statistics.obj`, `sub_aperture.obj`, `util.obj`, `util_block.obj`, `util_convert.obj` are created in the `Debug` folder of the project without any error, but some warnings like:

```
1>graphics.obj : warning LNK4006: _write_header_bmp_8bit already defined in 
PolSARproLib.obj; second definition ignored
```

[image]

[image]

I have created a folder named `Arii` and placed the following 22 files in the subfolder `\Arii\lib`

[image]

I have also the file `arii_anned_3components_decomposition.c` placed in the folder `Arii`:

[image]

Now I create the project `arii_anned_3components_decomposition` in the folder `Arii` as follows ([here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx_9vCAvXd5kM0NKTXlkbjhweE0) I’ve uploaded the project)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the following 2 pictures, you see the configuration of the project. Again, I should say that I’m working on a Win 10x64 machine

[image]

[image]

External library is added to the project as follows:

```
Properties>C/C++>General>Additional Include directories
```

I enter the path to the folder in which header files `.h` are placed

[image]

```
Properties>Linker>General>Additional library directories
```

I enter the path to the folder in which `.lib` files are placed

[image]

In

```
Properties>Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies
```

I’ve entered name of those needed `.lib` files:

[image]

Here is the beginning (before main function) of the file `arii_anned_3components_decomposition.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "omp.h"

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <dos.h>
#include <conio.h>
#endif

/* ROUTINES DECLARATION */
#include "../lib/PolSARproLib.h"
```

Now I build the solution:

[image]

And unfortunately I get 104 errors. 100 of them is about multiple definition of the functions in `util.h`, `util_convert.h`, `util_block.h` (those functions are listed in the beginning of question)

Errors 1-100 are alike:

```
1>PolSARproLib.lib(PolSARproLib.obj) : error LNK2005: _C3_to_T3 already 
defined in PolSARproLib.lib(util_convert.obj)
```

[image]

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx_9vCAvXd5kN2JoQ3dDSXI2bjg) I’ve uploaded the `error and warning file.txt`

- **I really don’t understand why am I getting these errors regarding that the code blocks `#ifndef #define #endif` have been used in the
  code?**

Comment: Why on earth would you `#include *.c`? Only include header files, *never* `.c` or `.cpp` files

Comment: I don't see an image of a cat.

Comment: @manni66 what do you mean?

Comment: @CoryKramer you mean to make the `.lib` file without `PolSARpro.c`? In fact the code is a part of  [PolSARpro version 5.1.1](https://www.ietr.fr/polsarpro/) project. They've written the code like this not me. I just know that `arii_anned_3components_decomposition.exe` file in the downloaded package has a bug. So I'm trying to rebuild and debug it because I need the result for my project.

Comment: Pardon me. But why do you close the question? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [CoryKramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2296458/corykramer), we don't need the file `PolSARpro.c`, in fact we should never `#include` `.cpp` or `.c` files and this is what has been done in that file:

The contents of the file `PolSARproLib.c` is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <dos.h>
#include <conio.h>
#endif

/* ROUTINES DECLARATION */
#include "util.c"
#include "util_block.c"
#include "util_convert.c"
#include "graphics.c"
#include "matrix.c"
#include "processing.c"
#include "statistics.c"
#include "sub_aperture.c"
#include "my_utils.c"
```

So, in order to get rid of all those 100 `LNK2005` errors, simply place these 20 files (Omit `PolSARproLib.c`) in a folder

[image]

And do the next steps as stated in the question for creating and building the static library project `PolSARproLib.lib` file and for creating and building the console application project `arii_anned_3components_decomposition.exe` file.